# How can I get the Last Processed timestamp for an SSAS tabular cube?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

In SSMS I have connected to a SSAS tabular cube. When I view the properties screen I see the Last Processed timestamp of `11/24/2015 2:59:20 PM`.

If I use `SELECT LAST_DATA_UPDATE FROM $system.MDSchema_Cubes` I see a timestamp of `11/25/2015 12:13:28 PM` (if I adjust for the timezone).

If I open up the partitions screen for one of the tables in my cube I see that the most Last Processed timestamp is `11/25/2015 12:13:28 PM` which matches the value from the DMV.

I want the Last Processed timestamp for my BISM, the one from the Database Properties screen, not the one from a partition that happened to be processed later.

Is there a way to get this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the code in the Analysis Services Stored Procedure assembly I was able to put together a powershell script that got the date I was looking for. Here is the code:

```
#we want to always stop the script if any error occurs
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$error.Clear()

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices") | Out-Null

$databases = @('BISM1', 'BISM2')
$servers = @('Server1\BISM', 'Server2\BISM')

function Get-BISMLastProcessed
{
  param(
    [string] $connStr
  )
  Begin {
    $server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
    $server.Connect($connStr)
  }
  Process {
    Try {
    $database = $server.Databases.GetByName($_)
    Write-Host "  Database [$($database.Name)] was last processed $($database.LastProcessed)"
    }
    Catch [System.Exception] {
      Write-Host $Error[0].Exception
    }
    Finally {
      if ($database -ne $null) {
          $database.Dispose()
      }    
    }
  }
  End {
    $server.Dispose()
  }
}


foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $connectStr = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BISM1;Data Source=$server"
  Write-Host "Server [$server]"
  $databases | Get-BISMLastProcessed $connectStr
  Write-Host "----------------"
}
```

The results are:

```
Server [Server1\BISM]
  Database [BISM1] was last processed 11/30/2015 12:25:48
  Database [BISM2] was last processed 12/01/2015 15:53:56
----------------
Server [Server2\BISM]
  Database [BISM1] was last processed 11/30/2015 12:19:32
  Database [BISM2] was last processed 11/02/2015 23:46:34
----------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Analysis Services Stored Procedure assembly that you can download from [here](https://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CubeInfo&referringTitle=Home).

Once you get the assembly file that corresponds to your Analysis Server version connect to your instance via SSMS.

1. Look for your your Database (Database Cube)
2. Go to Assemblies folder
3. Right click and `New Assembly...`
4. Browse and select the assembly.
5. Set the permissions as described in the documentation assembly
6. Once you have imported the assembly use this MDX query to get the last processed timestamp.

--

```
with member [Measures].[LastProcessed] as ASSP.GetCubeLastProcessedDate()
select [Measures].[LastProcessed] on 0
from [Armetales DWH]
```

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Is there a version that I can use with a tabular instance of SSAS? It appears that this one is for Multidimensional.

Comment: @SteveS. If you have a Tabular Instance you should not use `cube` word in your question, it is confusing since Multidimensional model is related to cubes and dimensions while Tabular model uses tables and relationships for modeling data.